# How to implement Custom Log Levels in CocoaLumberJack from Swift?

Tags: swift, cocoalumberjack

I am using CocoaLumberjack for a Swift project. I would like to implement custom log levels/flags, as I would like to use 6 rather than the default 5, and would prefer different names.

The [documentation for doing this](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack/blob/master/Documentation/CustomLogLevels.md) is not helpful.  It is only a solution for Objective-C.

The fact that [`DDLogFlag` is defined as `NS_OPTIONS`](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack/blob/master/Sources/CocoaLumberjack/include/CocoaLumberjack/DDLog.h#L115-L140) means I actually could simply ignore the pre-defined values here, create my own constants, and just write some wrapping code to convert from one to the other.

However, [`DDLogLevel` is defined as `NS_ENUM`](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack/blob/master/Sources/CocoaLumberjack/include/CocoaLumberjack/DDLog.h#L145-L180), which means Swift won't be very happy with me trying to instantiate something to say `0b111111`, which isn't an existing value in the enum.  If it were an `NS_OPTIONS`, like `DDLogFlag`, I could just ignore the pre-existing definitions from the library and use whatever valid `UInt` values I wanted to.

As far as I can tell, I just have to write some Objective-C code to define my own replacements for `DDLogLevel`, `DDLogFlag`, and write a custom function to pass this in to and access these properties on `DDLogMessage`.  But this feels bad.

**How can I use my own custom logging levels in Swift with CocoaLumberjack?**

Comment: https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack/pull/1249

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed only possible in Objective-C right now - and there also only for the `#define` Log Macros. Even then I could imagine that the "modern" ObjC compiler will warn about the types that are passed to `DDLogMessage`.

The docs are indeed a bit outdated here and stem from a time where Objective-C was closer to C that it is to Swift nowadays... :-)

Nevertheless, in the end `DDLogLevel` and `DDLogFlag` are both stored as `NSUInteger`. Which means it can *theoretically* take any `NSUInteger` value (aka `UInt` in Swift).

To define your own levels, you would simply create an `enum MyLogLevel: UInt { /*...*/ }` and then write your own logging functions.
Those functions *can* actually forward to the existing functions:

```swift
extension DDLogFlag {
   public static let fatal = DDLogFlag(rawValue: 0x0001)
   public static let failure = DDLogFlag(rawValue: 0x0010)
}

public enum MyLogLevel: UInt {
    case fatal = 0x0001
    case failure = 0x0011
}

extension MyLogLevel {
    public static var defaultLevel: MyLogLevel = .fatal
}

@inlinable
public func LogFatal(_ message: @autoclosure () -> Any,
                       level: MyLogLevel = .defaultLevel,
                       context: Int = 0,
                       file: StaticString = #file,
                       function: StaticString = #function,
                       line: UInt = #line,
                       tag: Any? = nil,
                       asynchronous async: Bool = asyncLoggingEnabled,
                       ddlog: DDLog = .sharedInstance) {
    _DDLogMessage(message(), level: unsafeBitCast(level, to: DDLogLevel.self), flag: .fatal, context: context, file: file, function: function, line: line, tag: tag, asynchronous: async, ddlog: ddlog)
}
```

The `unsafeBitCast` here works, because in the end it's just an `UInt` and `_DDLogMessage` does not switch over the level, but instead does a bit mask check against the `flag`.

---

**Disclaimer:** I'm a CocoaLumberjack maintainer myself.

---

We don't recommend using a custom log level in Swift. There's not much benefit from it and logging frameworks like [swift-log](https://github.com/apple/swift-log) also use [predefined log levels](https://github.com/apple/swift-log/blob/main/Sources/Logging/Logging.swift#L737).

However, I personally could also imagine declaring `DDLogLevel` with `NS_OPTIONS` instead of `NS_ENUM`. The OSLog Swift overlay also uses an extensible [OSLogType](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/oslogtype).
If this is something you'd like to see, please open a PR so we can discuss it with the team. We need to be a bit careful with API compatibility, but like I said it's totally doable.

On a side-note: May I ask what you need custom levels for?

Comment: I will open a PR for `NS_ENUM` -> `NS_OPTIONS` for `DDLogLevel` and use that PR as a jumping off point for discussing my needs.  Mechanically, this is the smallest possible change needed to allow me to more easily have my own custom log levels, but I do not know whether or not this is the best overall change for CocoaLumberjack that could accommodate my needs.  GitHub PRs are a bit better location for back-and-forth discussion.